# Using Google App Engine SDK for Python with Python 3

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, google-app-engine

I have both Python 3.5.2 and Python 2.7.12 Installed (On Windows). But when I try to deploy from Using Google App Engine SDK for Python, I receive this error message:

```
in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
2016-08-17 11:28:50 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I can only deploy from the command line:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" update app.yaml
```

Is there a way to deploy with Python 2 and not Python 3? Without using the command line? And how do I report to Google about this bug, I think if they want they can fix it for Google App Engine SDK.

Comment: Looks like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10227164/5272038) might be able to solve your problem.

Comment: @ShubhamVasaikar Thank you, it worked!

Comment: In my case I was accidentally in a Python virtualenv that messed things up, "deactivate" helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the correct Python path, when you have multiple copies of Python the wrong path might be selected as the default.

Usually it's `C:\Python27\pythonw.exe` however it may be something else if you changed that during installation.

Go to the Google App Engine Launcher and change the path to the one you want in Edit/Preferences.

Comment: Thank you, I used `C:\Python27\python.exe` and it works. It also works with `C:\Python27\pythonw.exe`, does it matter which one I select?

Comment: pythonw.exe is for GUI applications and python.exe is for terminal applications. It's described in depth here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe