# Run Python File In Python Shell or Directly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just a beginner in Python. I created a file called as `cc.py` and saved in the following path :

`C:/Python33/cc.py`.

I am trying to run this file but nothing is happening.

In the python shell I am typing `Python cc.py` but I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried an alternative :

```
>>> execfile('cc.py');
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('cc.py');
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

The file contains the following lines of code :

```
 import urllib

 htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://google.com")

 htmltext = htmlfile.read()

 print htmltext
```

How should I run this file? I am totally confused. Can someone help me out?

Comment: How were you "trying to run this file" and given the Syntax error I think we need to see the code, Have you got a simple print("Hello") working?

Comment: The syntax error is coming because he is typing it in the interpreter, not command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3, `execfile` no longer exists. You can open it and execute it manually:

```
def xfile(afile, globalz=None, localz=None):
    with open(afile, "r") as fh:
        exec(fh.read(), globalz, localz)
```

And to execute:

```
>>> xfile(r'C:\path\to\file\script.py')
```

Credit to: [What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0)

That's how you execute files from the interpreter.

Another way, you can execute it from the command prompt. Just open it and type:

```
$ cd filepath
$ python file.py
```

About the script you're running, there's also a confusion. Whatever example you are following, it's a Python 2 example, yet you are using Python 3. Change the request line to this:

```
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://google.com")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this too .. I typed after opening cmd.exe : cd Python33 and then I typed `python cc.py` but nothing happened

Comment: where do I need to write `xfile` ?

Comment: Just copy paste the code to your interpreter, in the space `>>> `.

Comment: I am getting the following error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    xfile(r'C:\Python33\cc.py')
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 3, in xfile
    exec(fh.read(), globalz, localz)
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'`

Comment: should I uninstall Python3.3 and install Python2.7 instead ??

Comment: That's up to you. If you feel like it, go ahead. But my solution is enough to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`print htmltext` should be `print(htmltext)`. Also, `execfile()` was removed from Python 3. It seems you are using a Python 2 book but running Python 3. These different versions of Python are incompatible, stick to one. For choosing which version, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170921/should-i-learn-python-2-before-3-or-start-directly-from-python-3).

An implemention of `execfile()`:

```
def execfile(filename, *args, **kwargs):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        exec(fp.read(), *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> In the python shell I am typing Python cc.py but I am getting the following error:
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If you want to run the python script, don't do it from the python shell. The "python" (not "Python") command needs to be run from a command prompt (DOS shell, terminal window, etc).

From a command prompt you should issue the command:

```
$ python cc.py
```

For a more complete description of the problem and solution, see [Executing Scripts](http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#executing-scripts) in the windows section of the python user guide, and also [How do I run a python program under windows](http://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows) in the frequently asked question section of the python users guide.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.yourwebsiteurl.com") as url:
     htmltext = url.read()
     print (htmltext)
```

Comment: Add some explanation to clarify your answer