# String Pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.x

*Trying* to move my application to Python 3.4...

My code:

```
    def Continue(self):
        exec(open(b"file.py").read())
```

My error:

```
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

My (miss)understanding is that by prefixing the filename string with a 'b' I am turning it into the required bytes like object.

Can anyone elighten me?

Comment: I think the file is read in as bytes. Try exec(open("file.py").read().decode("ascii"))) or encode. You can also try decode("ascii", "ignore") which will ignore errors that occur.

Comment: Thanks - error is 'str object has no attribute decode'

Comment: I'm not certain if I was sufficiently clear with my question - I'm trying to call a Python script from within another. In Python 2.x I'd have simply used exec("file.py")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0)

Basically open the file, read it, compile the code, and run it.

```
with open("somefile.py") as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), "somefile.py", 'exec')
    exec(code, global_vars, local_vars)
```