# PyCharm and Python Console

Tags: python, python-2.7, console, pycharm

I am trying to configure PyCharm: I need to write my script in the main editing window and then I want to check in the Python console window whether the results (variables, lists) work as expected.

Nonetheless, as I start using the Python console after running the script, the console has not collected any data from the running process.

Comment: do you mind editing your answer to include your code here as well?

Comment: Have you put in a breakpoint? See https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/debugging.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Python Console" is a separate environment from the one you run code in when you press "Run...".

First of all: Use the excellent debugging facilities provided by PyCharm to step through your code and see whether things work as they should *in situ.*

If that for some reason doesn't do it for you:

You can `from <yourfile> import *` in the console, if running pure python. That will get you your variables. If you do `import <yourfile>`, the script will be run, but your variables will only be available as `<yourfile>.<var>`. Of course, anything you have under `if __name__ == '__main__'` won't be executed.

If this won't do, I refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/a/437857/3745323:

```
with open("yourfile.py") as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), "yourfile.py", 'exec')
    exec(code, global_vars, local_vars)
```

You can definen that as a function in a separate file and import it. Alternatively, just type it into the interpreter.

If you have IPython installed, recent PyCharm editions default to using it in the console. In this case you can use the `%run` magic to run your script as if it was typed in line-by-line into the interpreter.

```
In[2]: %run yourfile
```