# Read python function from a text file and assign it to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have a text file that contains Python function like this:

**a.txt**

```
def func():
    var = 5
    return var
```

And then I read this file in a Python script:

**b.py**

```
python_file = open("a.txt").read()
```

Now I want to assign the `a.txt` file's function to a variable without worrying about the function name and execute it. I tried something like this:

```
python_file = open("a.txt").read()
b = exec(python_file)
b()
```

But it didn't work, I tried `execfile` as well.

Comment: Why don't you just rename it to `.py` and `import` it in the normal way? Either way, note that `exec` doesn't return anything, read its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sir It is .txt file. so cant import . and the requirement is such I don't know  function name of txt file  in python file.

Comment: ...a Python file *is* also just a text file, why not `os.rename` it?

Comment: I want to keep It txt file . In future the python function will come from database as string

Comment: Do you not think that kind of information would be useful in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you've `exec`uted the string, you can call `func` directly, as it has been added to your current namespace:

```
>>> exec("""def func():
    var = 5  # note that the semicolons are redundant and unpythonic
    return var""")
>>> func()
5
```

Per [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) `exec` doesn't actually return anything, so there's no point assigning e.g. `foo = exec(...)`.

---

To see what names are locally defined in the code being executed, pass an empty dictionary to `exec` as the `locals` parameter:

```
>>> ns = {}
>>> exec("""def func():
    var = 5
    return var""", globals(), ns)
>>> ns
{'func': <function func at 0x0315F540>}
```

You can then assign the function and call it as you normally would:

```
>>> b, = ns.values()  # this will only work if only one name was defined
>>> b()
5
```

Comment: I don't want to call it by function name. I don't know the function name in python file. I wanna assign to a variable what ever function is there

Comment: @AshishNautiyal well that's probably going to be tough. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: agreed Sir .But I want to find a way to assign it to a variable .

Comment: I have added how you can do that, but you still haven't really answered my questions.

Comment: Read strings check syntax, save as .py and import it(when import deleted it if want dynamic load).

Comment: @SDilmac how does that solve the problem? If you have a separate answer, please add it as an answer

Comment: @AshishNautiyal I suspect with a sufficiently well-written regex you could find out the function's name.

Answer (score 2):

Before offering my solution, I highly warn against do this unless you know for sure there is no malicious code in *a.txt*.

My solution uses the `execfile` function to load the text file and return the first object (could be a variable or function):

```
def load_function(filename):
    """ Assume that filename contains only 1 function """
    global_var = dict()
    execfile(filename, global_var)
    del global_var['__builtins__']
    return next(global_var.itervalues())

# Use it
myfunction = load_function('a.txt')
print myfunction()
```

## Update

To be a little more careful, modify the return line like the following so that it skips variables (it cannot skip class declaration, however).

```
    return next(f for f in global_var.itervalues() if callable(f))
```

## Update 2

Thank you johnsharpe for pointing out that there is no `execfile` in Python 3. Here is a modified solution which use `exec` instead. This time, the function should be found in the "local" scope.

```
def load_function(filename):
    """ Assume that filename contains only 1 function """
    with open(filename) as f:
        file_contents = f.read()
        global_var = dict()
        local_var = dict()
        exec file_contents in global_var, local_var
        return next(f for f in local_var.itervalues() if callable(f))

# Use it
myfunction = load_function('a.txt')
print myfunction()
```

Comment: Note that Python 3 doesn't have `execfile`, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins, http://stackoverflow.com/q/436198/3001761

Comment: My bad. I don't have Python 3. In that case, your solution (open text file, read contents, call exec) combine with mine (get the first callable from the global name space) will work.