# Move list from iPython cell into datafile

Tags: python, list, file, csv, ipython

I have the following data, currently stored in a Python list:

```
formant_data = [ 
    'ɑ',  
     125, 150, 10,
     580,  50, 10,
     780,  50,  9,
    1010,  50, 10,
    2530, 100,  9,
    4400, 150,  8,
    5300, 200,  8,
    5880, 200,  7,
    7420, 200,  7,
    8860, 200,  7,

    'a',
     168, 120, 10,
     680,  50,  9,
    1000,  50,  9,
    1500, 150,  8,
    2500, 200,  7,
    5200, 800,  7,
    7200, 400,  6,
    8500, 400,  6,

    'ɛ',
     150, 120, 10,
     700,  50,  8,
     750,  50,  8,
    1800, 150,  8,
]
```

And I am unpacking it as follows:

```
import numpy as np

vowels = deque()
acc = deque()
for x in reversed(formant_data):
    if isinstance(x,str):
        symbol = x
        print(symbol)
        data = np.reshape( acc, (-1,3) )
        vowels.appendleft(data)
        acc.clear()
    else:
        acc.appendleft(x)
return vowels
```

I wish to move the data into a text file, and read it in.

What's the simplest way to do it?

I don't mind fiddling around with the data file format. The main objective is that it be easily readable.

EDIT: Maybe I can just save it as `data.py` and `import data.py` ? problem: I want it to reside in `input/data.py`

EDIT: %run magic?

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1:** (Similar option to your **EDIT**)

You can store simply your list in a file called `data_file.py` and then do `from data_file import *`

**OPTION 2:** (given by [jez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3019689/jez) in the comments)

More efficient, but a little bit tricky to understand. You can store simply your list in a file called `data_file.py` and then do in your code:

```
container = {}
exec(open('data_file.py').read(), container)
```

**OPTION 3:**

You can store all the content in the list in a .txt or .whatever file, and then read all the content of the file and split it by "," as follows:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input:
    content = input.read()
    list = content.split(',')
```

And then you'll be able to do whatever you want with your list.

Comment: Instead of `import`, use `execfile`.  If you want some control over where the variables end up,  say  `container = {};  execfile(filename, container)`.  The reason for preferring `execfile` over `import` is that, once you have imported `data.py` once, its content will be cached and subsequent imports of the same file will yield the old data regardless of recent changes.  With either `import` or `execfile`, note the security implications, since you're allowing your interpreter to execute arbitrary commands written in what may or may not be a benign "data" file.

Comment: You're right, but `execfile` is not valid for all python versions

Comment: Argh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0 why Python WHY?

Answer (score 1):

For better security than `import` or `exec`, while maintaining readability, use the standard [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module:

To save:

```
import json
with open( filename, 'wt' ) as datafile:
    json.dump( formant_data, datafile, indent=3 )
```

To load:

```
import json
with open( filename, 'rt' ) as datafile:
    formant_data = json.load( datafile )
```

This gives you flexibility as to how you want to format the data.  `json` serialization supports the `dict` type, which is presumably a more natural way of associating the numbers with each of your phonemes.

Comment: Removed the alternative `pickle`-based code since `pickle` isn't secure either.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for adding iPython to the question late -- I didn't think it was relevant, but it turns out iPython has a `%run` magic:

```
%run input/formant_data.py
```

While I'm going with this, I'm grateful for the other answers. I think `import` would require [packaging](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data), as the file is not in the current folder.