# Equivalent of source() of R in Python

Tags: python, execute

Like we have `source()` function to execute a `R` program in another `R` program in R studio, how do I execute a python program in another python program?

Comment: This question provides a related approach to this: [What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given 2 python scripts: `first.py` and `second.py`, the usual way to execute the first from the second is something in the lines of:

first.py:

```
def func1():
    print 'inside func1 in first.py'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # first.py executed as a script
    func1()
```

second.py:

```
import first

def second_func():
    print 'inside second_func in second.py'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # second.py executed as a script
    second_func()
    first.func1() # executing a function from first.py
```

**Edits**:

- You could also go for the simple `execfile("second.py")` if you wish (although it is only within the calling namespace).
- And a final option is using [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) like so:
  `os.system("second.py")`.

Comment: I found the `execfile` to be most similar to R's `source`

Comment: I agree with vpipkt. It might not be the most Pythonic way of doing things, but sometimes I just want to execute another Python script as though it were within the first script (which is what `source()` does in R). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3?noredirect=1&lq=1) was also helpful.

Comment: Regarding note by @ldos on the first bullet of their edited answer: "(although it is only within the calling namespace)": to avoid this issue, we can use `runfile()` from the `sitecustomize` package so that the included script is run in its own namespace.
In my scenario, this characteristic is particulary crucial because from the included script I need to access the `__file__` property which, when using `execfile()` resolves to the file name of the _calling_ script! (not useful to me, since inside the included script, I need to retrieve its directory location)

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to sourcing directly from GitHub, you can use the requests package to download the raw *.py file with an http get, and then execute the file.

```
import requests
exec(requests.get('http://github.myorg.net/raw/repo/directory/file.py').text)
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm an R user learning Python, so this might be violating some Python best practices