# How to import variables from Python script into interactive shell like in R?

Tags: python, r

If I have an R script called `arscript.r` with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/R
newvar = 10
```

then in the R interactive shell I can do

```
> source("./arscript.r")
> newvar
[1] 10
```

I would like to do the equivalent in Python. How would it be possible? Obviously in Python I would write `print(newvar)`...

Comment: `"./test.r"` or `"./arscript.r"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360008/equivalent-of-source-of-r-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

In python you can import a script and then call variables from it:

for example, file blah.py looks like this

```
text = 'abc'
```

and another file run.py looks like this:

```
import blah
print (blah.text)
```

which prints

```
> abc
```

(in this case, the files have to be in the same folder)

Comment: As I said, I would like to be able to continue working on the variables from the script in the interactive shell.

Comment: so then you need to use something like Jupyter Notebook

Comment: @TMOTTM and you *can* do that. How, exactly, does this not work for you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What do you mean by 'that'? I find it convenient to work with an interactive shell next to a script so I can define a complicated expression that stores a value/array/.. in a variable. Then I can "import" the script in the shell and interactively explore what I can do with this variable. That's what I like about the R interpreter and what I would wish for to do in Python shell.

Comment: Do you mean Rstudio?