# Use variables in a textfile as input

Tags: python, input, text-files, var

As the topic says..

I want to use the file

indata.txt:

```
f=lambda x,y:-2*x*y
xa=0
xb=2
A=2 
n=18
```

Into my big program:

```
from math import *

'''Function which calculates the d.e. using runge-kuttas formula'''
def runge(f,xa,xb,A,n):
    .....



indata=open("indata.txt","r")
runge(f,xa,xb,A,n)
indata.close()
```

So my question is:
How to I use the variables in the text file indata.txt as input to the bigger program?

Comment: Looks like python, why not just call it `indata.py` and import it?

Comment: It's python, sorry for not mentionting that. The project require it to be a textfile

Comment: You can still import it via filename, see the dupe I linked.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you could use one of two options:
 1. Rename your file to `inpdata.py` as mentioned in comments and in your main file use

```
from inpdata import *
```

2. Use built in python `execfile()` [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile). For Python3 `execfile()` alternative look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: [Alternative for Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0)

Comment: @M.T Thank you for helpful addition!