# How to reduce Django class based view boilerplate

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, boilerplate

I really hate boilerplate. However, I can't deny that code such as the following is a huge benefit. So my question, what does one do in Python to make up for the fact that it doesn't come with a macro (template) pre-processor?

One idea would be to write a factory function, but I'll willingly admit that I don't know where to start. (Please note that this is Django with its declarative classes and interesting "magic" metaclassy stuff going on underneath, which I know enough to recognise and not enough to understand or debug if I break it)

The other would be to turn this into a template and import it through a trivial pre-processor that implements something like `${var:-default}` in Bash. (see [What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0) ),

```
with my_preprocessor("somefile.py") as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), "somefile.py", 'exec')
    exec(code) # in the current namespace
```

But there are lots of warnings about `exec` that I've seen over the years. The cited SO answer mentions line numbers for debugging as an issue. Then there is this, http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/ , warning of subtle problems including memory leaks. I suspect they won't apply to a code defining classes which are "never" deleted, but on the other hand I don't want the slightest risk of introducing obscure problems to a production setting.

Any thoughts or pointers welcome. Is the best thing to do is to accept cut and paste boilerplate? There are unlikely to be more than twenty paste-modifies of any such template, usually less than ten.

Example code. Lines marked #V are the only ones that would commonly be customized. The first two classes are used once only, by the third.

```
#--- this is boilerplate for a select-view ----
#--- just replace the string "User" by the relevant model and customize 

class UserSelectPopupTable( tables.Table):

     id = SelectorColumn( clickme='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>' ) #V

     class Meta:
        model=User
        attrs={ 'class':'paleblue' }
        empty_text='Sorry, that search did not match anything.'
        fields=( 'name','address', )        #V
        sequence=('id','name','address',)   #V

class UserFilter2(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')     #V
    address = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')  #V
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name','address', )   #V (usually same as previous)

class UserSelectPopup( FilterTableView ):
    model=User
    table_class=UserSelectPopupTable
    filterset_class=UserFilter2
    template_name='redacted/select_in_popup.html' 

#--- end boilerplate
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use these generated classes?

Comment: as views: `url(r'^UserSelectPopup/$', views.UserSelectPopup.as_view(), name ='userselectpopup'), `

Comment: Writing a factory has turned out a lot easier than I thought. I read and re-read `type` 3-arg doc and then ... will answer own question after a bit more testing and tidying.

Answer (score 2):

Python and Django are awesome.

I read and re-read the (quite short) documentation of the 3-argument form of `type` that you use to dynamically create classes (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). I  wrote a trivial helper routine `Classfactory` to provide a better interface to `type`, and translated the class structure into function calls, which was mostly cut and paste! I arrived at the following (which I think also proves that you can write Javascript in Python ... the instinct to insert semicolons was strong)

```
def Classfactory( classname, inheritsfrom=(object,), **kwargs):
    inh = inheritsfrom if isinstance(inheritsfrom, tuple) else (inheritsfrom, )
    return type( classname, inh, kwargs)

ThisPopupFilter = Classfactory( 'ThisPopupFilter', django_filters.FilterSet,

    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains') ,
    address = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains') ,
    Meta = Classfactory( 'Meta', 
        model = User,
        fields = ('name','address', ),
    ),
)
ThisPopupTable = Classfactory( 'ThisPopupTable', tables.Table, 

    id = SelectorColumn( clickme='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>' ),

    Meta = Classfactory( 'Meta', # default inherit from object
        model=User,
        attrs={ 'class':'paleblue' },
        empty_text='Sorry, that search did not match anything.',
        fields=( 'name','address', ) ,
        sequence=('id','name','address',) ,
    ),
)

UserSelectPopup = Classfactory( 'UserSelectPopup', FilterTableView, 
    model=User,
    table_class=ThisPopupTable,
    filterset_class=ThisPopupFilter,
    template_name='silson/select_in_popup.html', # this template handles any such view
)
```

Now I suddenly realized that it's not just Django `Meta` classes that can be defined inside other classes. Any class that is not needed elsewhere can be nested in the scope where it is needed. So I moved the first two classes inside the third, and then with a bit more rearranging I was able to move to a factory function with arguments ...

```
def SelectPopupFactory( Model, fields, sequence=None, 
                clickme='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>' ,
                empty_text='Sorry, that search did not match anything.',):
    return Classfactory( 'UserSelectPopup', FilterTableView, 

    model=Model,
    template_name='silson/select_in_popup.html', # this template handles any such view

    table_class=Classfactory( 'ThisPopupTable', tables.Table,   
        id = SelectorColumn( clickme=clickme ),
        Meta = Classfactory( 'Meta', # default inherit from object
            model=Model,
            attrs={ 'class':'paleblue' },
            empty_text=empty_text,
            fields=fields,
            sequence=sequence,
    )),
    filterset_class=Classfactory( 'ThisPopupFilter', django_filters.FilterSet,
        name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains') ,
        address = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains') ,
        Meta = Classfactory( 'Meta', 
            model = Model,
            fields = ('name','address', ),
    )),
)

UserSelectPopup = SelectPopupFactory( User, 
    fields=('name','address', ), 
    sequence=('id','name','address',) ,
    )
```

Can anybody see anything fundamentally wrong with this? (I'm feeling slightly amazed that it all ran and did not crash at the first attempt, modulo typos)

UPDATE a workday later: I think this is OK as an example / proof of concept (it is code that ran without crashing) but there are several fine points to do with the actual django_filters and django_tables2 usage that aren't right here. My factory function has evolved and is more capable, but less easy to relate to the original non-factory class definitions.