# How do I execute a python program on a different terminal?

Tags: python

So, I am trying to make a program that executes various programs; so say i have P1.py, P2.py and P3.py; I want to execute P1, P2 and P3 in 3 different terminals while still being able to use the main program(The one that opened the 3). How could I do this?

Comment: Did you intend to tag your question as [openproject]? I've retagged it as [python] unless you want to clarify that it was the right tag.

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which platform are you on? You literally want 4 console windows open on your desktop?

Comment: This is very platform dependent.On windows its easy, if you use the `subprocess` module, just add `creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` to your call.

Comment: On linux, there are multiple console implementations. I use `gnome-terminal` but `xterm`, `konsole` and many others exist. My environment says `TERM=xterm` but I don't have `xterm` on my system., so it can be hit-and-miss what works.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 16.03

Comment: tdelaney, I tried using gnome-terminal on the os module(so it sends the command "gnome-terminal" and then "python P1.py, python P2.py, etc" and "./P1.py, etc" ) but that doesnt seem to work; It does open the terminal though.

Comment: Thank you mcNets, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

Imagine P1.py contains:

```
def function1():
    print("P1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function1()
```

To execute P1.py from P2.py:

```
import P1
def function2():
    print ("P2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function2()
    P1.function1()
```

If you are using python2 you can simply use this code in P2.py

```
execfile("P1.py")
```

Comment: This question might help to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0

Comment: This isn't running the programs in different windows so I don't see how it helps.

Comment: Vibhutha Kumarage, yeah i know, but i want the program to execute in a different window