# How do i execute a py module by pressing a button in another pymodule

Tags: python, button

Hello i like to execute another py module by pressing a button, so far i cant get it to work, and this is what i have.

```
   def callback():
       exececfile('JSONandDB')
   b3 = Button(root, text='Import', command=callback) 
   b3.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=10, pady=12)
```

Comment: `exececfile` should probably be `execfile`. Please post the full error if that is not the only issue.

Comment: def callback():
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

Comment: Which python version do you use?

Comment: python version 3.6

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16577427/3901060)

Comment: Thanks for the links, defintly game me some answers.