# IPython evaluate file from local directory

Tags: python, ipython

I'm wondering how I would go about evaluating the definitions of a python file in the directory my IPython REPL is running in. This would seem like a great workflow to be able to test the functions I just wrote inside the REPL.

This doesn't work:

```
with open('file.py') as f: eval(f.read())
```

Comment: Maybe just `import` it?

Comment: Note that [this specific answer on the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41658346/364696) covers an `ipython` specific trick to do this.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille How does that work?