# How to emulate Py_Main in pure Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a Python program that emulates the behavior of Py_Main when running a Python script. In other words, I want to behavior similar to running `python some_file.py` from the command line, but inside of my Python script. In my case, I'm running inside a parallel programming environment and it is important to say in the same process (so I can use shared memory), so I can't just shell out to a new Python interpreter.

You can use `execfile` ([or `compile` followed by `exec` in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/437857/188046)) to load the file itself. However, from some initial testing, I've found at least 4 differences between `execfile` and `Py_Main`:

1. `execfile` does not set `__file__` correctly. By default it inherits the parent's globals, and therefore will see the parent's value of `__file__`. In order to work around this you have to create a new dictionary for globals and set `__file__` yourself.
2. Similar to the above, `execfile` does not set `__name__` by default. You would have to set it to something (e.g. `__main__`) yourself.
3. In fact, `execfile` does not create a new module at all. You can work around this by using [`imp.new_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.new_module) to create a fresh module, which you could use as the global scope for `execfile`.
4. Because `execfile` doesn't create a module, it doesn't add it to `sys.modules`. However, you have to be careful doing this: e.g. `__main__` might already be in `sys.modules` if you're executing the top-level script as `python top_level.py`. I'm not sure there's a clean way around this except hiding the current value of `__main__` and restoring it afterwards. You could use another value, but then you wouldn't be following the normal Python conventions associated with executing scripts.
5. `execfile` does not add the directory of the file to `sys.path`. As a result, you can't `import` another module in the same directory from inside the script, which is something that works with `python some_script.py`.

None of these are insurmountable problems, but I'm concerned this isn't a closed set, and that if I go this route I'll continue to find behaviors that I haven't modeled correctly in my solution.

My question:

1. Is there a way to implement this in Python such that I can be sure I'm correctly modeling all the behaviors of `Py_Main`?
2. Failing that, is there at least a C API I could use that would do this, considering that the Python interpreter may already be initialized (i.e. I cannot just call `Py_Main`). E.g. does [`PyRun_SimpleFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_SimpleFile) have the behavior I want? From the documentation, this is not at all obvious.
3. Or, in the worst case, is there at least documentation on what exactly `Py_Main` is doing, so that I can determine what I do or do not what to spend effort imitating in Python? The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.Py_Main) is pretty vague, and all of the above I determined by manually comparing with the behavior of `execfile`.

**Edit:** A note about `runpy`: After asking this question, I discovered the [`runpy.run_path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_path) function. At first glance, this looked like the solution I needed. However, it does not address my point #5 above. Specifically, it's possible to observe the difference between `runpy.run_path("some_dir/test_execfile_helper.py")` and `python some_dir/test_execfile_helper.py` in this scenario:

```
$ cat test_execfile.py
import runpy
runpy.run_path("some_dir/test_execfile_helper.py")

$ cat some_dir/test_execfile_helper.py
print("attempting to import some_other_file")
import some_other_file

$ cat some_dir/some_other_file.py
print("in some_other_file.py")

$ python some_dir/test_execfile_helper.py 
attempting to import some_other_file
in some_other_file.py

$ python test_execfile.py
attempting to import some_other_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_execfile.py", line 2, in <module>
    runpy.run_path("some_dir/test_execfile_helper.py")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 252, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, path_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "some_dir/test_execfile_helper.py", line 2, in <module>
    import some_other_file
ImportError: No module named some_other_file
```

So, perhaps this is a better starting point than `execfile`, but my original critique still stands: I still have no way of knowing if the list of issues listed above is a closed set.