# Running python script with exec problem nltk

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, exec

I am trying to run a python script with exec in PHP.

if I run it on anaconda it works properly.

But with exec or cmd the library nltk give an error:

```
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

py = 3.7

Answer (score 0):

exec(open("./filename").read())

follow this thread it might be helpfull:

[What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Exec I call it in php and not in python.