# Is there ever a good reason to put python code in a txt file?

Tags: python, python-import, execfile

I noticed a file `include.txt` in every project I open. The file contains python code:

```
from aws_xray_sdk.core import patch_all
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.aws_lambda import AwsLambdaIntegration

# pragma: no cover
patch_all()

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn=...,
    integrations=[AwsLambdaIntegration()]
)
```

That file is then being executed with `execfile(os.path...+'/include.txt')` in multiple files within that project.

I'm sure the code is necessary. But why not name it `include.py` and then `import` it?

I have just recently joined the company, so I have asked a few people who have been around the longest, and nobody knows why.

I'm tempted to rename the `txt` to `py` and change `execfile` to `import`, but I'm worried that maybe there was a good reason for doing it that way. Possibly my change would appear to look fine but then have some distant unforeseen consequences.

So, is there ever a **good** reason put python code in a `txt` file?

UPDATE:

We're using python 3.7.

Nothing from the `include.txt` is mentioned anywhere else in the project code -- no references to `sentry` or `X-ray`.

In every module, `execfile` is imported just before the call:

```
from past.builtins import execfile
```

Comment: `import` is different because the module has its own namespace. `execfile()` executes the code in the current script's namespace.

Comment: Note that `execfile` is gone in Python 3. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3

Comment: Maybe you have a compatibility library loaded? The name isn't defined in 3.9.2.

Comment: My bet is someone made https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3#16577427 into a function that’s also imported in the same module.

Comment: It's `from past.builtins import execfile`